# How do I debug why handler for "click" JavaScript event doesn't get called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I've installed a handler for the `click` JavaScript event of a `<button>` element using the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/click/), but the handler doesn't get called when the button is in fact clicked. How can I debug why the event handler isn't invoked? I'm developing in Visual Studio 2010 and debugging with the help of Google Chrome Developer Tools.

I'm new to JavaScript and don't know the debugging methods :)

**EDIT**

This is the HTML declaration of the button in question:

```
<button id="start-lint">Submit</button>
```

The relevant JavaScript:

```
$('button').button();
var btn = $("button#start-lint");
log.debug("Button: %s", btn);
btn.click(function () {
    log.debug("Button clicked");
});
```

Let me know if more information is needed.

**EDIT 2**

Somehow I got it working, not sure what was wrong in the first place, but at least now I know how to tell if an element was found or not!

Comment: Show us some code! (Most likely your selector is wrong, so you're not binding to the element that you want to..)

Comment: How do you bind the click event to the button? Hard to debug without anything happening.

Comment: do you see any error in the console? if not then most probably the selector is wrong as Dexter said it...

Comment: @Dexter See my edit; however, my question is not what I'm doing wrong, but how to debug issues like this. No code should really be needed to answer that question?

Comment: Have you tried using internet explorer ? i have this problem sometime vs don't debug to other browser but IE

Comment: @Sarawut Positwinyu I tried now, but I don't get any log output from log4javascript (while in Chrome I do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only debug if the code is actually fired, which it seems to not be.

You could try to see if its even finding the selector using length.
alert($("#myselector").length);
or 
console.log($("#myselector").length);

For debugging javascript i recommend you to use FIREBUG for Firefox (http://getfirebug.com/) - you can set breakpoints, write to console etc, and it gives all possible displays of variables, objects etc.
Tutorial can be found here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xxfvuZFHsM

(You said you where new to jQuery/Javascript, so hope it helped :D)

Comment: I've logged the length of the button and it is 1, so apparently it is found (conversely, I tried a non-existent ID and length was then 0). Looks like a valuable technique, thanks! Is Firebug better than Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: Oh okay :)  Chrome Developer is just as good. Firebug might be easier to use for first timers, but if your already using Chrome Developer no need to switch - just as powerfull! Glad to see you got it working!

Answer (score 4):

Inline JavaScript is executed as the page loads, so if the button is defined after the JavaScript the code won't find it and so can't attach the handler. You need to put that JavaScript in the document ready (or onload) function, which means it will be executed after the button (and everything else on the page) has loaded, and/or put it after the button in the source.

Comment: You can also use the .delegate() function to add the property to any new element that is created and matches the given selector

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the `$('button').button();` throws an exception, and the rest of your code isn't executed.  Comment out that line and see if it works.

**Original reply:**

1. Paste your code, or the relevant parts of it.
2. Add a `debugger;` statement to your handler function to see if you are entering it.
3. If not, then there is a problem with how you're registering the handler.
4. If you are entering it, maybe there is a problem with the handler itself.

Comment: I've a debug logging statement in the handler, and I can tell it isn't entered, so what I need to debug is why the handler isn't correctly installed. Isn't there some tool that can help me determine which handler is installed for the "click" event?

Answer (score 1):

your button may look like this

```
<input type="button" value="Click" />
```

for this you bind a click handler like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='button']").click(function(e){
        alert("somebody clicked a button");
        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6gCRF/5/

but the drawback of this approach is it will get called for every button click, to prevent that you might want to add an id to your button and select that specific button e.g.

```
<input type="button" value="Click" id="specific" />
```

attach a click handler to it like

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#specific").click(function(){
    alert("specific button clicked");
    });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6gCRF/4/

**EDIT**

in your case select the button by id

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#start-lint").clcik(function(){

    console.log("clicked");
    });
});
```

you can also use the pseudo `:button` selector

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":button").click(function(e){
            console.log("clicked");
            });
});
```

[**have a look at jquery selectors**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: AFAICT your last example corresponds to what I'm doing (see my pasted code).

Comment: @aknuds1  look closely you are using `button` and i used `:button` notice the colon `:`